# Angular2 router VS ui-router-ng2 VS ngrx router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular2-routing, ngrx

What are the benefits and disadvantages of using [ui-router-ng2](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng2.html) instead of the new Angular2 router? In the past i used ui-router with Angular 1.x instead of using ngRoute, because i need better support for nested states/routes.

So now, what about Angular2? I would like to hear by you so i can evaluate both opportunities.

Besides, searching and searching on Google i found [ngrx/router](https://github.com/ngrx/router), that i didn't know.
Can you tell me what are the differences between the **builtin router** of Angular2, the new **ui-router** for Angular2 and **ngrx router**?

Comment: ngrx/router is DEPRECATED for angular 2 -> https://github.com/ngrx/router

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## General information

***NGRX Route*r** [docs](https://github.com/ngrx/router)

ngrx router is *Deprecated*! There is [migration strategy](https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/docs/overview/migration.md) from ngrx router to the standard Angular2 Router.

***Angular2 Router*** [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

1. Default solution from Angular team
2. Was inspired by UI-router from AngularJS
3. Built for components

Angular2 Router has almost all UI-router features.

***NG2 UI-router*** [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/)

Well known UI-router from AngularJS updated for the Angular2. From the known advantages - makes smoother update from AngularJS UI-router to ng2 UI-router.

## Comparing

Let's compare syntax of UI-router both versions with Angular2 Router.

*AngularJS UI-router* :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
});
```

*Angular2 UI-router* :

```
export let state1: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    url: '/home'
}

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   SharedModule,
   UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: [home] })
 ],
declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

*Angular2 Router* :

(**Update:** property - `name` was removed after V3-alpha7. Because it didn't work out with lazy loading of routes.)

```
import {
    RouteConfig,
    Route
} from 'angular2/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home';

@Component({})
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ 
        path: '/home', 
        component: HomeComponent, 
        name: 'Home' // Deprecated property, works until v3-alpha7
    })
])
export class App {...}
```

As we can see, in general, Angular2 Router is pretty much the same. As addition need to say that it support most of the common features like static/dynamic data sharing through the routes, nested views etc.

- Same location strategies (Path and Hash)
- Similar route definitions
- Similar services:

  - $state.go and Router.navigate
  - $stateParams and RouteParams
  - $state.current.data and RouteData
- Similar directives

  - ui-view and router-outlet
  - ui-sref and routerLink

## Conclusion

Angular2 Router had taken best of UI-router experience and implemented it. If you need easy migrate your code base with AngularJS UI-router to Angular2 fast and smoothly, you can try Ng2 UI-router, otherwise, I think Angular2 Router will fit best. Even if you decided to use NG2 UI-router, check all pros and cons, at current point I feel like the community is going to choose a standard solution from the Angular team which means better support.

Comment: Having a couple of Angular 1.x apps, including a 1.5.x app with components, there may be a compelling argument to stick with ui-router, as it's finalizing component routing support for NG1 with components. The Angular team appear to be almost at the point of [scrapping plans for a backport](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15163) of the NG2 router for NG1 apps. Also, the UI-Router docs just got a facelift and seem greatly improved over the last time I looked at them.

Comment: We've tried both and the state based Angular 2 UI-Router is our first choice by far, just like it was when we were building Angular 1 apps. Support is excellent. Highly recommend it over Angular 2 stock router.

Comment: @demisx can you clarify the reasons for choosing UI-Router over Angular 2 Router? In my oppinion the main feature differences are named states, default and non-url parameter values in UI Router (which could be sufficient arguments). Did you consider any other differences?

Comment: @demisx, my main message here is that new angular router was created with ideas of ui-router, so the difference is not big. But you are getting angular development team if you are choosing angular default router with almost same features as in ui-router.

Comment: I wouldn't say the Angular 2 router is almost the same as UI Router. Not in my personal and my team's opinion. Sure, Angular 2 tried to copy some features from it, but UI Router's state-based UI is one of the biggest advantages over a URL path-based Angular 2 router, IMHO. Also, folks coming from the AngularJS world would have a much better experience porting their existing or developing new apps in Angular 2/4, since the UI-router is pretty much de facto router in Angular 1 world.

Comment: NOTE: Even through this was answered after the final release of Angular v2 in September, the shown router code is for the deprecated router.

Comment: If you need named router-outlets AND a normal looking URL, look into UI Router. Currently named outlets in the default router have really poor URLs. (eg `foo.com/my-route(outletA:componentA//outletB:componentB)`)

Comment: One feature that seems to be supported by ui-router but not by angular's default router is typed parameters; default router parameters are always strings AFAIK.

Comment: Angular2 UI-router is not state bases and completely different from UIRouter, I don't understand why you say its almost the same?